# Basic outline of how to compute a string scattering amplitdue

Tags: string-theory

Recently I have been trying to understand how string scattering amplitudes are calculated via integration over the moduli space of Riemann surfaces. I am mathematician with almost no physics background so I find the literature regarding the path integral formulation of the string scattering amplitude difficult to follow.

This is my very basic understanding:

1. The worldsheet propagated by a bosonic string is a Riemann surface. Therefore, we will want to formulate the string scattering amplitudes as a integrals over the moduli space of Riemann surfaces.
2. From what I have gathered, this first thing we need to do is define an action $S$. Is this the integral of some Lagrangian taken over the moduli space of Riemann surfaces? What exactly is the action $S$ supposed to represent?
3. After this it seems we need to define something called a "partition function". What is this function and how is it defined?

Anyway, as you can see, I am struggling to understand exactly what steps are involved in computing a string scattering amplitude and am hoping somebody will be able to give a brief outline of the procedure.

Comment: Maybe page 20 of this thesis is of (partial) help as a summary of the ideas.
https://livrepository.liverpool.ac.uk/3003839/

Comment: consider calculating scattering amplitude in a simpler theory first, like QED?